# How to set the text color dynamically inside the Picker control for xamarinForms- UWP APPs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I am having a requirment of changing the text color of each item inside the Picker dynamically for UWP APPs.

For example, Now the Picker shows the list of Names,
so if the default flag is 0, I want to change the text color to red, if the Flag is 1 change the text color to green, etc.
Is there a way to achieve this? Please suggest

Comment: can you post your code for the picker se we can just add the color changing part ?

Comment: There is not enough information about your real scenario. Like @javirs said, please post the code that you are using now.

Comment: Xaml Code:<Picker
                            x:Name="PickupPicker"
                            TextColor="#015F83"   
                            FontSize="24"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RequestLocationList}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding LOCATION}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPickUPLocation,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            >
                        </Picker>

Comment: The above code gives always the black color of text when Picker opens.
      My requirement is to modify the location color based on a few flags from API as mentioned in the description.

Comment: If you want to bind things to values, your best bet is to have a viewmodel where you store the color of the item and, in the getter of this property, you define the logic  behind the decision. Then from the page you bind to this color.

Comment: I tried binding the text color property through the ViewModel, but it doesn't seem to reflect the color inside the Picker view. So need help on PickerRenderer for the UWP app to modify the text color of an item inside the Picker control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picker's TextColor property can just change the selected item's text color. If you want to change the display items' text color, you can try to use the custom renderer.

I have created a sample and changed the item's text color. The picker in the xamarin is a control which inherited from the ComboBox in the uwp. So you can create a style to set the ComboBox's Foreground property.

Such as: in the app.xaml(uwp project part):

```
<Application
x:Class="AppTest.UWP.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppTest.UWP">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Name="customtype">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style></ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in the customrender:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker),typeof(MyPickerRender))]
namespace AppTest.UWP
{

public class MyPickerRender : PickerRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.ItemContainerStyle = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["customtype"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Style;
    }
}
}
```

And because you want to set different color according to different value of the flag, so you can create two style and use different style according to the flag.